# @Autowired bean property is null in @Configuration bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with @Autowired property in @Configuration bean.

I have a bean similar to the one below:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Autowired MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Bean
    MongoDbMetadataStore indexMetadataStore() {
        return new MongoDbMetadataStore(mongoTemplate, "index");
    }
}
```

and ... mongoTemplate is null while creating indexMetadataStore bean (checked with debugger). Unfortunately I cannot provide entire project structure, it is large (it has ~5 XML config files and around 20-30 @Configuration beans) and my bet is that there could a circular reference or something of sort.

However, this mongoTemplate bean is created earlier and injected to other beans (also checked with debugger), so at this point mongoTemplate is fully created and I cannot understand why it is not injected and left null.

Any ideas where I should look?

Comment: package of MyConfig class is included in your component scan?

Comment: You may be required to use the `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` annotation. Without seeing a complete example, it's just guessing though. http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html

Comment: The annotation `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` seems to have been removed in Spring 4.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out a problem. I will describe it here, so that perhaps someone else may find this answer useful and save precious time resolving it :).

It turned out that there was a circular reference and Spring was doing its best to initialize and use not-fully-initialized config objects. There were `config1` and `config2` beans (both `@Configuration`) that used objects from each other.

It is interesting to know that in such a situation Spring tries to initialize `@Resource`, `@Autowired` and `@Value` in the following order:

1. `@Resource` is initialized first, in the order that objects were declared in the `@Configuration` bean
2. `@Value` is treated as `@Autowired`. Hence, `@Value` and `@Autowired` are initialized in the order of appearance AFTER all `@Resource` beans are initialized.

It is important to understand the above order, because your beans and circular reference may rely on `@Value` settings and such setting may still be `null` while creating a resource referenced from other config bean.

However, the best strategy is to avoid circular references and finally that is what I did - put offending resources to new, third, config bean.

Answer (score 1):

The order statement seems to be true. I have a number of @Autowired properties in my @Configuration bean. Those at the end of the list appear as null when trying to use them in my @Bean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Autowired 
  private MyClass myClass;
  @Autowired 
  private MyClass2 myClass2;
  ...
  @Autowired 
  private MyArgument1 myArgument1;
  @Autowired 
  private MyArgument2 myArgument2;

  @Bean(name = "myList")
  public List<MyInterface> getMyList() { //given MyArgument1 & MyArgument2 implement MyInterface
    List<MyInterface> myList= new ArraList<MyInterface>();

    myList.add(myArgument1); //resolved as null 
    myList.add(myArgument2); //resolved as null

    return myList;
}
```

}

If I put them in the top of the list they are resolved properly. So.. how many should I count on being properly resolved? Need a better approach.

This is working

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  @Autowired 
  private MyClass myClass;
  @Autowired 
  private MyClass2 myClass2;
  ...

  @Bean(name = "myList")
  public List<myInterface> getMyList((@Qualifier("myArgument1") MyInterface myArgument1, (@Qualifier("myArgument2") MyInterface myArgument2) { //given myArgument1 & myArgument 2 are properly labeled as @Component("myArgument1") & @Component("myArgument2")

    List<myInterface> myList= new ArraList<myInterface>();

    myList.add(myArgument1); //resolved!
    myList.add(myArgument2); //resolved!

    return myList;
}
```

}

This seems to implement the right dependency